# Find & Replace via ssh - send a result via mail

Tags: email, replace, cron

I'm having a small issue, i'm running and cron task every 5 minutes  which is looking text chain and replacing it with nothing..
In order to optmize something i would like to add a new function to my cronstrask : send me an email if it replaces something.. if the crontask does not find the chain no need to send a mail. I have  no idea how to do that , maybe you can help me .
Here is my current cron task :

```
find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$chain if would like to era$ $g'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that I did with help of other poeple. 
It will maybe help some other poeple

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -r -q 'stringtoreplace' /home/     #Find the string in all files on my home
if [ $? == 0 ] #if the  last result fit  then
then
        echo "At the following time : " $(date +%H:%M:%S) | mail -s "[Serveur Leaked] Bad iframe has been found " my@mail #we send a mail with the date
        find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$stringtoreplace$ $g' #we replace the string with a whitespace
else
        exit 1
fi
exit 0
```